# Integration with respect to a function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I'm trying to figure out how some authors got from here:

$$
V_{ij}=\int_{a_{L}}^{a_{ij}} a^{1-\epsilon}dG(a)
$$

where

$$
G(a)=\frac{a_{ij}^k-a_{L}^k}{a_{H}^k-a_{L}^k}
$$

to this expression:

$$
V_{ij}=\frac{k(a_{ij}^{k-\epsilon+1}-a_{L}^{k-\epsilon+1})}{(k-\epsilon+1)(a_{H}^{k}-a_{L}^{k})}
$$

Is the property of the Riemann-Stieltje integral whereby

$$
V_{ij}=\int_{a_{L}}^{a_{ij}} a^{1-\epsilon}G'(a)da
$$

part of solving the problem?

Thanks!